SQL Server Rounding Too Early
Here is an example query for my question:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ExampleData
CREATE TABLE #ExampleData ( [ProratePercent] decimal(38,19) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #ExampleData ([ProratePercent])
VALUES
( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),
( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),
( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),
( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),
( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),
( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),
( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),( 0.0434782608695652174 ),
( 0.0434782608695652173 ),( 0.0434782608695652173 )
  
SELECT  CAST(225 AS decimal(38,19)) * ProratePercent, ProratePercent
FROM    #ExampleData

This creates some percentages that I calculate in my real code.
NOTE that the last two end in a 3, while the rest end in a 4
It then multiplies them by the total value (225) to get the prorated value.
When it does the multiplication, the resulting value is 9.782608695652174 for each row.  This is rounded at 15 digits.
I then just run the math directly.
SELECT  225 * 0.0434782608695652173
SELECT  225 * 0.0434782608695652174

This gets me the values that I was hoping to get above:
9.7826086956521738925
9.7826086956521739150
How can I get the actual SQL to give me the full number?
I have tried:
SELECT  CAST(225 AS decimal(38,19)) * ProratePercent, ProratePercent
FROM    #ExampleData

Surprisingly this caused loss of even more precision.  Giving a value of 9.782609 for each row. (6 places of precision)

See also the "Remarks" section of the Precision, scale, and length documentation - in particular footnote 1. Bottom line - you need to give the calculation "room to breathe", or the fractional part will be sacrificed to reserve enough digits on the integer side. In you case, it would be sufficient to calculate 225 * CAST(ProratePercent AS decimal(20,19)), which would yield a decimal(24,19) result or 225 * CAST(ProratePercent AS decimal(34,19)), which would yield a decimal(38,19) result.

...See this db<>fiddle. The actual choices for precision and scale should be based on the expected range of values for ProratePercent and the 255 multiplier. It is best not to just throw assorted precision and scale values at the problem to achieve a "seems to work" result without understanding the reason and knowing that the selected values will work properly for all expected cases.

Do you really need this precision? What are you calculating?

If you define your column's data type correctly, as well, you get the "correct" results: db<>fiddle.

See the "Remarks" section of the Precision, scale, and length documentation - in particular footnote 1.

Bottom line - you need to give the calculation "room to breathe", or the fractional part will be sacrificed to reserve enough digits on the integer side. In you case, it would be sufficient to calculate 225 * CAST(ProratePercent AS decimal(20,19)), which would yield a decimal(24,19) result or 225 * CAST(ProratePercent AS decimal(34,19)), which would yield a decimal(38,19) result.
Note: The above is based on the inline constant 225 being treated as decimal(3,0). If that value were instead an integer typed variable, column, or expression, it would be treated as decimal(10,0), and the calculated result type would also be different.

I found this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77664/how-does-sql-server-determine-precision-scale
It showed that if you convert each and every operand AND the final result to the type you want, then there is no rounding.
For my example, this is a way to do it:
SELECT  CONVERT(decimal(38,30), CONVERT(decimal(38,30),225) * 
            CONVERT(decimal(38,30), ProratePercent))
FROM    #ExampleData


I wouldn't say this is a way to go; if you are storing values between 0 and 1, with no more than 19 digits after the decimal point, why do you also need to be able to store 19 digits before the decimal point in your table? The problem is the choice of data type in your table, not the expression. By defining a precision of 38 digits, you are exhausting the data type; are you really going to need to store a value that might be as large as 9999999999999999999.9999999999999999999? If you are, and the you multiply that by 999 would you prefer loss of scale, or an overflow error?

@ThomA - I am not using this scale.  I just picked something with a really large precision to get my point across.

The scale isn't the issue, it's the precision; it's 38. The problem would occur with a decimal(38,3) as well.
